# How to check a list of filenames on a shared google drive against a list of 6 figure item numbers and automatically check a box

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

Per header. I have a list of produts with 6-digit item numbers. I need to cross-reference that against a list of filenames that refer to these products and automatically tick a checkbox if they are present. The 6-digit numbers can appear anywhere in the filename.

I've tried importing a list of filenames (including within subfolders) using an existing script into another sheet tab and doing a vlookup, but this times out before it finishes importing all of the filenames so it's not working for me and seems an overly-complicated and slow way of doing what I want.

Is there any way of doing what I want, or even a workaround that's fater than manually searching each of the 2000 or so item numbers in google drive?

Comment: I can't directly share the file as it's got proprietary info but I'll make one like it. I should have explained better initially that I dint necessarily need to import the list of files, just search it and report if the matches are there or not.

Comment: Here's a link to a facsimile of the file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iOInsOP3AK87Rvqgz-7OS02Cm7xkp8jKRv5Jymr6KAY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **Google Apps Script**. I have replicated your situation and came up with a working code. Please see code below(I have tried this on my end and it is working properly):

```
function myFunction() {
  driveFiles = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles(); // REPLACE folderId with the folder containing all your files to check
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  lastRow = ss.getLastRow()
  itemNums = ss.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, 1).getValues();
  while(driveFiles.hasNext()){
    fileName = driveFiles.next().getName();
    for(row in itemNums){
      if(fileName.includes(itemNums[row])){
         Logger.log(ss.getRange(row, 5).getValue());
         ss.getRange(row, 5).check()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You may need to modify/tweak the code a bit in order for it to work as you want it to be on your end.

Comment: Thanks for the script. I'm getting this error though: Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp. (line 2, file "TEst 2") I'd be really grateful for any insights on solving that one.

Comment: Are you using the correct folder id of your google drive folder?

Comment: I've solved that part, and have tested it with some dummy files with the 6 figure references as their names. The script completes successfully, but the sheet is unchanged. What do you see when you test it?

Comment: The tickbox on column E is being checked whenever I run the script and the 6 digit reference is satisfied.